# A problem with writing nanosecond timestamps to a millisecond precision database in cnosdb

Tags: database, sqldatatypes, cnosdb

I created a database with millisecond precision

```sql
create database ms with precision 'ms';
```

and wrote a timestamp with nanosecond precision into it.

```sql
create table ms_t (value BIGINT,tags(str));
insert into ms_t (time,str,value) values (1682049219172428000,'asd',1);
```

After the write was successful, the select query displayed the following.

[image]

I expect the correct result to be returned